# How to make a GraphQL mutation with a property that is an array of data?

Tags: javascript, graphql, graphql-js

I have a situation where a user can save a contact record with some associated tags at the same time.  To do this I have a mutation called "createContact" that is responsible for that action.  The schema for this mutation looks like this:

```
const Mutation = new graphQL.GraphQLObjectType({
name: 'Mutation',
fields: {
  createContact: {
    type: Contact,
    description: "Create Contact",
    args: {
      _id:  {type: new graphQL.GraphQLNonNull(graphQL.GraphQLString)},
      name: {type: new graphQL.GraphQLNonNull(graphQL.GraphQLString)},
      tags: {type: new graphQL.GraphQLList(TagInput)}
    },
    resolve: function(source, args, context) {

    // There is usually some DB code here to save data

    return args;
    }
  }
 }
});
```

I ran into some problems in a previous implementation having not created an InputType analog to my query ObjectType for tags, so I created the following InputType for the Tags:

```
const TagInput = new graphQL.GraphQLInputObjectType({
  name: 'TagInput',
  description: 'Input type variation for the tag record for use in  mutations',
  fields: () => ({
    name: {
      type: graphQL.GraphQLString
    }
  })
 });
```

I test my setup with the following query:

```
{
  "query": "mutation createNewContact { 
                  contact: createContact ( 
                        _id: "contactID1", 
                        name: "John Smith", 
                        tags: [
                          { name: "friend" }, 
                          { name: "co-worker"}
                        ] 
                  ) 
                 {
                  _id, 
                  name, 
                  tags { 
                     name 
                   } 
                 } 
  } 
}
```

The query seems to work okay as there are no errors that are thrown and all of the data from the request makes it into the resolver, but for some reason that I have yet to figure out, it never returns the tag data in the response.  The response I receive instead is this:

```
{
 "data": {
    "contact": {
        "_id": "contactID1",
        "name": "John Smith",
        "tags": []
    }
 }
}
```

This happens both when I am returning the args straight without any DB actions or when I do DB actions in it.  I have been trying to figure this out for a while now but have no idea why there are no tags being returned in the response.  If anyone has any ideas I would love to hear them.  Thanks!

Edit:

This is the Object Type that I have for my Contact:

Contact:

```
const Contact = new graphQL.GraphQLObjectType({
  name: 'Contact',
  description: 'Contact record',
  fields: () => ({
      _id: {
        type: graphQL.GraphQLID
      },
      name: {
        type: graphQL.GraphQLString
      },
      tags: {
        type: new graphQL.GraphQLList(Tag),
        resolve: function(src, args, context) {
          return TagModel.findByContactId(src._id)
            .then(tags => {
              return Promise.map(tags, (tag) => {
                return TagModel.findById(tag.tag_id);
              });
            });
        }
      }
  })
});
```

Comment: Based on this code it definitely seems like it should work. Can you post some code for your object type definitions and resolvers? Might be something there.

Comment: Specifically, we need to see what the Contact type looks like, along with its resolvers.

Comment: @AndrewIngram Sorry it took so long to respond.  I don't have an input type for the Contact.  I only have an object type for the Contact for queries.  I thought that returning the arguments as they came in in the resolver would just keep the proper format of the properties I sent in and would regurgitate them (this is a test case as I couldn't get it to work with actual records from the DB either).  Is there something I am fundamentally missing in all of this?

Comment: @stubailo I added the code I have for my Contacts Object Type, though I'm not sure how that comes into play for the mutations.  Am I missing something in this regard?